# regular expression accepting a range of integer and decimal

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which could match the following range of numbers:

```
1,9 - 29,9 and 30-549
```

This is what I managed to write so far but it only accept decimal for exple it will accept 29,9 and not 27.
this is my regex:

```
^(1\.9\d*|[2-9]\.\d*|[2-9]\.?|1[0-9]\.\d*|1[0-9]\.?|2[0-8]\.\d*|29\.[0-9]|3[0-9]\.?|[3-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|5[0-4][0-9])$
```

Comment: What is `1,9 - 29,9`?

Comment: Regexes are not a good tool to check number ranges. Converto to numbers and use arithmetic comparators (`<=`) instead. Testing cases are simpler, code is simpler, and it's way more readble.

Comment: @Kasramvd Decimal point probably. A lot of countries use `,` instead of `.` for decimal point.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ohum, seems too!

Comment: @ Kasramvd , 1,9 - 29,9 are the range of number I need to test

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:[1-9],[0-9]|[12][0-9],[0-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|5[0-4][0-9])$
```

Comment: Pleasee try my suggestion. It matches 1 decimal after 1-29 (add an asterisk * if you allow 0 or more or add a plus after [0-9]` to allow 1 or more decimal numbers, and matches integers from 30 to 549. There was a problem with brackets as they were not pasted correctly (I'm on a mobile phone).

Comment: @  stribizhev oh I see, thank you very much. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I find the solution. for a range **1,9 to 29,9** (decimals and integers) and **30 to 549** (integers only), this regex will work:

**^(1\,9\d*|[2-9]\,\d*|[2-9]\,?|1[0-9]\,\d*|1[0-9]\,?|2[0-8]\,\d*|2[0-8]|29\,[0-9]|29|3[0-9]\,?|[3-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|5[0-4][0-9])$**